# Sorting 8 arrays by 1 key array, plus issue Last name first name, sorting

Tags: c#

Code below. Idea is to sort the Last name array and have all the data move in relation to the last name, so here is the sample data:

```
         Amy    Wilson  21  68.5    190 150 10
         Scott  Wilson  25  76.5    250 210 10
         Jamie  Scott   45  62  150 135 56
         Sharon Baxter  52  65  150 140 8
         Brock  Stanley 65  70  180 190 4
         Baxter Cash    18  72  170 200 8
         John   Stanford    30  74  190 210 7
         Angel  Delgado 25  62.5    150 137 5
         Brad   Harris  55  70  200 180 6
         Amber  Carrell 18  65  120 110 3
         Jakob  Neihaus 20  64  110 120 3
         Willie Mitchell    23  68  150 170 6
         Melia  Mugano  18  67  167 145 7
```

And here is what it should look like sorted:

```
        Sharon  Baxter  52  65  150 140 8
        Amber   Carrell 18  65  120 110 3
        Baxter  Cash    18  72  170 200 8
        Angel   Delgado 25  62.5    150 137 5
        Brad    Harris  55  70  200 180 6
        Willie  Mitchell    23  68  150 170 6
        Melia   Mugano  18  67  167 145 7
        Jakob   Neihaus 20  64  110 120 3
        Jamie   Scott   45  62  150 135 56
        John    Stanford    30  74  190 210 7
        Brock   Stanley 65  70  180 190 4
        Amy Wilson  21  68.5    190 150 10
        Scott   Wilson  25  76.5    250 210 10
```

Here is what I am getting

```
        Sharon  Baxter  52  68.5    190 150 10
        Amber   Carrell 18  76.5    250 210 10
        Baxter  Cash    18  62  150 135 56
        Angel   Delgado 25  65  150 140 8
        Brad    Harris  55  70  180 190 4
        Willie  Mitchell    23  72  170 200 8
        Melia   Mugano  18  74  190 210 7
        Jakob   Neihaus 20  62.5    150 137 5
        Jamie   Scott   45  70  200 180 6
        John    Stanford    30  65  120 110 3
        Brock   Stanley 65  64  110 120 3
        Amy Wilson  21  67  167 145 7
        Scott   Wilson  25  68  150 170 6
```

As an additional issue when I sort again, Amy and Scott Wilson switch places, all the rest of the data stays sorted.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
private void sortArray()
{

    string[]  clientFirstnameArray = new string[mMaxClients];
    string[]  clientLastnameArray = new string[mMaxClients];
    int[]  clientAgeArray = new int[mMaxClients];
    double[] clientHeightArray = new double[mMaxClients];
    double[] clientStartWeightArray = new double[mMaxClients];
    double[] goalWeightArray = new double[mMaxClients];
    int[] weeksArray = new int[mMaxClients];

    for (int index = 0; index < mNumClient; index++)
    {
        clientLastnameArray[index] = mClients[index].LastName;
        clientFirstnameArray[index] = mClients[index].FirstName;
        clientAgeArray[index] = mClients[index].Age;
        clientHeightArray[index] = mClients[index].Height;
        clientStartWeightArray[index] = mClients[index].StartWeight;
        goalWeightArray[index] = mClients[index].GoalWeight;
        weeksArray[index] = mClients[index].Weeks;

    }
    string[] copy_clientLastnameArray = new string[mMaxClients];

    Array.Copy(clientLastnameArray, 0, copy_clientLastnameArray, 0, mNumClient);
    Array.Sort(clientLastnameArray, clientFirstnameArray, 0, mNumClient);
    Array.Sort(copy_clientLastnameArray, clientAgeArray, 0, mNumClient);
    Array.Sort(copy_clientLastnameArray, clientHeightArray, 0, mNumClient);
    Array.Sort(copy_clientLastnameArray, clientStartWeightArray, 0, mNumClient);
    Array.Sort(copy_clientLastnameArray, goalWeightArray, 0, mNumClient);
    Array.Sort(copy_clientLastnameArray, weeksArray, 0, mNumClient);


    for (int index = 0; index < mNumClient; index++)
    {
        mClients[index].LastName =  clientLastnameArray[index];
        mClients[index].FirstName =  clientFirstnameArray[index];
        mClients[index].Age =  clientAgeArray[index];
        mClients[index].Height = clientHeightArray[index];
        mClients[index].StartWeight = clientStartWeightArray[index];
        mClients[index].GoalWeight = goalWeightArray[index];
        mClients[index].Weeks = weeksArray[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be a lot easier to simply create an object with all the properties called Person, but it into a list and sort that list?

Comment: You appear to be using Hungarian notation :( Anyway, are all these arrays necessarily? Do they not relate in some way? Can you not have a parent class that has these properties so they have semantic meaning?

Comment: Yes, what Ela said. It's madness to have a separate array for each column like that. One type with one property for each column and a single array of that type is the way to go. In fact, it looks like you already have such a type - so why aren't you already doing this?

Comment: What @Ela said.. You already have mClients as a list of objects. Why not use mClients.OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ThenBy(x => x.FirstName) and you are done?

Comment: @Jakub *facepalm, you're right ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do what you're doing. You have a `Client` object already in the  `mClients` array. So just sort that directly, instead of splitting it into 7 arrays and sorting the arrays.

```
 List<Client> sortedClients = mClients.OrderBy(a => a.LastName)
                                      .ThenBy(b => b.FirstName)
                                      .ToList();
```